# This log is provided by the In-Memory Error Log. ** ELMAH**

Tags: asp.net, elmah

I included ELMAH (no configuration needed) to my web application

it seems working fine..

but I am worried of the log configuration that was setup automatically as:
This log is provided by the In-Memory Error Log.

my question is:

would this strain the resources and the RAM causing the application degradation ??

should I consider other setup like XML or SQL??

Regards

Comment: This is difficult to answer, as we have no idea what configuration (hardware-wise) you have on your system. I suggest running your application in a real-world setup with and without the in-memory settings to determine if it is "acceptable" or not.

Comment: thanks Karl, actually i am planning to host my app on a shared hosting plan .. so I think i am limited with resources :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that your in memory logging will not survive the application pool restarting or being shut down after a period of inactivity. It certainly will not survive a server restart, which with a good host (who is patching their systems) should happen at least monthly. If you have a database available to you then I'd recommend using that (there is a [script](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/downloads/detail?name=ELMAH-1.2-db-SQLServer.sql) available to create the tables), otherwise you could look at logging to LocalDb or XML which will persist the details of errors for you. It is also possible to configure Elmah to e-mail one or more addresses with details of exceptions as they occur. See the [sample web.config](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/downloads/detail?name=ELMAH-1.2-sp2-sample-web.config) file for details of configuration and syntax.

Lastly, if you are enabling remote access to the Elmah logs, make sure that you have [properly secured Elmah](http://www.troyhunt.com/2012/01/aspnet-session-hijacking-with-google.html) (read through if interested or just skip to "Protecting against this attack" for how to avoid it) to prevent unauthorised access and the potential for attackers to impersonate either you or your users. There is also an [article on the Elmah Wiki](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/SecuringErrorLogPages) that describes securing against remote access.

Comment: I decided that you answered the question, but I want to add the following; from the [link](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/errorloggingmodulesandhandlers.aspx) .. it says:  "Storing errors in memory is fast and suitable as long as they don't need to survive application restarts. Since application resets are often unpredictable this log provider is usually employed for testing and troubleshooting only;"

Comment: Smth bad happened with original Elmah repo, a lot of file are not accessible, use https://elmah.github.io/ intest.